# Adding a dropdown to a View

Tags: list-form, list-view

Is it possible to add a dropdownlist into one of the columns of a standard list view e.g. AllItems.aspx?

Comment: You are adding a drop-down list to a list view? What purpose would it serve? Is it to edit an item?

Comment: Yes exactly. Users want to specify the data for the column with a drop-down list without navigating to edit page. When they choose an option the list item will be updated automatically.
Maybe I need a client-side solution?

Answer (score 1):

Some additional thoughts:

- It's not possible to add any kind of custom control into a standard list view. The only possiblity is a custom field type which has a custom 'render pattern' - here you can only do certain things with CAML functions, rather than actually write .Net code. (N.B. This is by design, so that developers cannot create solutions which kill the performance of list pages)
- It *may* be possible to do something with the datasheet view, but personally I'd avoid it is there's quite a lot of MS stuff which goes on there, and since *heavy* customization would be required you would be in 'interesting' territory to say the least. Could be support implications there too I guess.
- **My suggestion would be to use SPGridView as a starting point** - this gives you the look and feel of a list and custom controls can be added. [Paul Robinson has a good post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by replacing the List View Web Part (LVWP) with a Data View Web Part (DVWP).  The DVWP can have only the one column editable.  If you don't want the users to have to click a Submit button, then you can use the Lists Web Service (UpdateListItems operation) and jQuery or JavaScript to do the updates "live" on the change event.  Check out my [jQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com). If you need help with it, then post the details in the Discussions there and I'll try to help you through it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain, but this might be possible using datasheet view and adding a javascript to the page to change the look. The datasheet view will allow editing and also includes the drop-downs if they are created that way in the list. Modifying the look with a javascript could give it the appearance of a regular list without affecting the function. I have not tested this, but I would think it would be possible.

Comment: Based on your idea, I think it is possible to change the contents of the grid column to a drop down list with javascript. When the selection changes list service can be called and list item can be updated.
What do you think?

Comment: Great idea Mossy